# What's going on with Laurits and his new "pet"?

Tags: plot-explanation, character, ragnarok-netflix

*This question contains spoilers for season two of Netflix's *Ragnarok*. You've been warned!*

---

About half way through season two of *Ragnarok*, Laurits acquires a new pet by highly unusual means (his surgery at the hospital). The pet is only shown a couple times and doesn't actually *do* anything but make noises, and then at the end of the season Laurits ends up releasing it into the wild.

**My question is, what purpose did the pet actually serve?** It basically just sat in Laurits' room the entire time and although his mom did make a fuss about it being in the house, nothing ever really came of it (I mean, aside from him eventually getting rid of it).

It definitely seems like the pet contributed to Laurits' overall character development but I just don't get how and why...

Answer (score 1):

I am pretty sure the pet is meant to be [Jörmungandr](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/J%C3%B6rmungandr). The medical procedure symbolizes the birth of the serpent. For now, they seem to only introduce it and want us to wonder what may happen. The existing myths, which are mentioned in the Wikipedia article I have linked above, hint to possible developments. I assume we will see some modern interpretation of this in Ragnarok in future episodes.